# Karma Server spawn UNKNOWN -4094 Error in Angular Unit Tests

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

For no understandable reason, I am no longer able to run unit tests in my Angular project because the Karma Server is throwing the odd error shown below.

I am simply running `npm test` to trigger the unit tests, which should launch a web browser to start the Karma server and then Jasmine to show the test execution.

This is on a Windows 10 PC using VS Code.

```
PS C:\Code\my-project> npm test
> my-project@1.0.0 test
> ng test
05 04 2022 13:45:19.898:WARN [karma-server]: Passing raw CLI options to `new Server(config, done)` is deprecated. Use `parseConfig(configFilePath, cliOptions, {promiseConfig: true, throwErrors: true})` to prepare a processed `Config` instance and pass that as the `config` argument instead.
⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...05 04 2022 13:45:30.857:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
05 04 2022 13:45:30.864:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.3.12 server started at http://localhost:9876/
05 04 2022 13:45:30.865:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
05 04 2022 13:45:30.872:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
05 04 2022 13:45:30.945:ERROR [karma-server]: UncaughtException: Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:667:9)
    at spawnWithSignal (child_process.js:871:17)
    at spawnWithoutOutput (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js:174:26)
    at Object.ProcessLauncher._execCommand (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js:75:21)
    at Object.ProcessLauncher._start (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js:33:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js:19:10)
    at Object.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at Object.BaseLauncher.start (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\base.js:52:10)
    at Object.j (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launcher.js:108:17)
    at Object.setTimeout.bind.j (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\qjobs\qjobs.js:143:18)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
05 04 2022 13:45:30.949:ERROR [karma-server]: Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at spawnWithSignal (child_process.js:871:17)
    at spawnWithoutOutput (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js:174:26)
    at Object.ProcessLauncher._execCommand (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js:75:21)
    at Object.ProcessLauncher._start (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js:33:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\process.js:19:10)
    at Object.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at Object.BaseLauncher.start (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launchers\base.js:52:10)
    at Object.j (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\karma\lib\launcher.js:108:17)
    at Object.setTimeout.bind.j (C:\Code\my-project\node_modules\qjobs\qjobs.js:143:18)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to uninstall and reinstall Google Chrome on my corporate laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution could be(point no. 2 worked for me)

1. Re-installing google chrome.(This might help users who uses local chrome.exe file)
2. My project was using chromium to run ChromeHeadless, I had to comment CHROME_BIN in karma-conf file which was pointing to chromium path. By doing so, Karma will take the local chrome.exe file(C:Program File\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe) instead of chromium path. This solution resolved my issue and I could run the test cases locally.